# "comm: file 1 is not in sorted order" when compiling R source in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, r

While compiling R source 2.15.1 in Windows 7, I get following error.

> comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
>
> make[3]: *** [R.dll] Error 1
>
> make[2]: *** [../../bin/i386/R.dll] Error 2
>
> make[1]: *** [rbuild]
>
> Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2

Basically I installed Rtools 2.15.1 before compiling the source with "make all recommended". Do I have to install any other software? I tried other OS such as windows 7, windows 2008, XP and results were consistent.

Comment: You might want to report this on the R-Developer list. There was a [recent post](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/file-2-is-not-in-sorted-order-error-building-unsuffered-consequences-td4616618.html) about it. Just make sure you are using only the dlls from Rtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise, R source 2.15.1 was not complete for Windows build. When I downloaded [patched version](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rpatched.html), I was able to compile everything without any problem.